# How to show manufacturer / hersteller in the order confirmation email?

Tags: shopware6

I´d like to show the manufacturer in the order confirmation e-mail. I know there is a variable for manufacturerID but I need the translated name of the manufacturer in my mail.

How can I do this?

Comment: We will need more info to go on. Since the order does not have a manufacturer ID, I can assume you are talking about line items? There might be a loop? Then there should be a reference to the original product from the line item?  Can you provide a snippet of the email template where "manufacturerID" is working?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show manufacturer name – or any other entity details – you have to make sure that entity is associated. If not, the `{{ lineItem.product.manufacturer.name }}` code will not be possible because manufacturer will not be included. So, you need to add entity association in specific criteria event if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested, but should be close enough that you can figure it out:

```
{{order.lineItems as lineItem}}
  {{lineItem.product.manufacturer.name}}
  // OR
  {{lineItem.product.manufacturer.translated.name}}
{{loop end}}
```

You can checkout the reference in the Github repository to figure out any data you wish: https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.4.18.0/src/Core/Checkout/Order/Aggregate/OrderLineItem/OrderLineItemDefinition.php